# Solving a LP feasibility using CGAL

Tags: algorithm, linear-programming, cgal

Can we solve linear programming feasibility problem of form mentioned below using CGAL(if not, please suggest alternatives):

`v.x_a > c` and,

`v.x_b = c`

where `v`,`x_a`,`x_b`,`c` are vector, vector, vector and scalar respectively. I want to find a tuple `(v,c)` for a given set of `x`( `x_a` and `x_b` are elements of `x`) which satisfies this inequality.

I have seen the [documentation](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/QP_solver/index.html#title0) but allowable form is of type `Ax(relation operator)b` where `relation operator` can be >=,<=  or =, where both `A` and `b` are known and `x` is unknown but my requirement is opposite, that is I have `x` but I want to determine if there exists a tuple `(A,b)` which satisfies the inequality.

**Context:** 
I am trying to implement a 3D mesh generator for which I need to test whether an edge(joins two 3D vertices) is Delaunay. *Delaunay edge* is defined as: An edge is Delaunay, iff there exists a circumsphere of its endpoints not containing any other vertex inside it.

My question is based on the approach described [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/19663/21170)

Comment: Isn't the inequality trivially true if you choose `v = c = 0`? Or even just `c = -infinity`?

Comment: Well I guess in the context of David Eppstein's algorithm, you have the additional restriction `v != 0` and `c = v.x` for a particular  `x` from the set

Comment: @NiklasB. Thanks, I have updated the question accordingly.

Comment: There is still a trivial solution, `v=1; c=-inf`. You should update the question to remove the ambiguity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the construction that David Eppstein describes in the linked question, `i` and `j` are fixed and we have the additional restriction that `v.xi = v.xj = c`. So the problem becomes:

> Find a vector `v != 0` such that `v.xk >= v.xi` for all k and `v.xi = v.xj`.

This can be transformed to

> Find a vector `v != 0` such that `(xk - xi).v >= 0` for all k and `(xi - xj).v >= 0` and `-(xi - xj).v >= 0`

By defining `A` as the matrix with rows `xk - xi` for all k, `xi - xj` and `xj - xi`, we get

> Find a vector `v != 0` such that `Av >= 0`

which has the form you need. You can enforce the `v != 0` by brute-forcing the non-zero component. For each component `i` and, trying adding the condition `vi >= 1` or `vi <= -1` and check the resulting system for solvability. Since the normal vector of the plane can be scaled arbitrarily, there is a solution iif any of the resulting programs is solvable (there are `2d` of them if `d` is the dimensionality of `v`).

Comment: I think `Av>=0; v!=0` seems more complete.

Comment: @Pranav I am just using the definition from Eppstein, nothing more or less. One condition is that v.xi = v.xj = c according to his description. This means that the two points corresponding to xi and xj  actually lie on the hyperplane

Comment: Agreed, Eppstein's formulation does not impose `v!=0`. Regarding xi,xj lying on a plane, it has already been taken care in `Av>=0`, in the way you have defined matrix `A`, right.

Comment: @Pranav Oh now I see what you mean. Updated

Comment: CGAL has only `{<=,>=,=}` relation operators to express constraints. Can we represent `v!=0` using this?

Comment: @Pranav Well you can just use v.v as the objective function to maximize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54114/discussion-between-pranav-and-niklas-b).

Comment: @Pranav I just noticed that the orientation of the plane is in fact important, so you need to check both for `vi >= 1` and for `vi <= -1` for each component `i`

Comment: Just to be sure I have understood the significance of orientation of the normal vector in this problem: Is `Av>=0; vi>=1` and `Av>=0; vi<=-1` equivalent to `Av>=0; vi>=1` and `Av<=0; vi>=1`?

Comment: Well yeah that's pretty basic algebra